# Sharepoint 2013 timer job run on development server but not on prodection server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have developed a custom timer job for SharePoint 2013 in visual studio 2012 which sends email notifications. The issue is that it works fine on development server.

I have followed the following steps to debug it on the development server

1. Deploy the timer job on respective site.
2. Restart the timer service in `services.msc`
3. Then is do attach to process `OWSTIMER` in visual studio.
4. And finally Go to SharePoint 2013 Central administration->Monitoring->Review Job Definition and click on the respective timer job and say run now.

After doing this the breakpoint is hit in visual studio at the `Execute()` method. So in the development server it is running.

Now on the production server I cannot debug using visual studio so I have deployed the packaged solution(.wsp).

I can see the feature is activated in Site Collection Administration-> Site Collection Features.

Now on the production server I follow the following steps

1. Restart the timer service in `services.msc`
2. And finally Go to SharePoint 2013 Central administration->Monitoring->Review Job

Further to test whether the timer job is working on production server or not I had used `PortalLog.LogString("Flow test1");` at the start of the `Execute()` method. Now this runs on the development server and I see the message in the SharePoint logs but on the production server I can't see "Flow Test1" in the logs after I click Run Now in central admin.

Can anyone suggest what is the issue and a possible solution?

Comment: how much time your timer job took for execution. check  Job history.

Comment: Can you get the timer job via PS? If so try to run it and then do a merge-splogfile in order to check all servers in the farm for your string

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple option to detect your timer job issue .

1. You will need to check your timer job service history and check
   status (like service will run or not )
2. Check SharePoint logs at same time
3. Check Event viewer that will also provide some help
4. Restart timer service in serivces.msc section

Answer (score -2):

Just restart the **timer service** through `services.msc`